# react native svg chart render duplicate text

Tags: javascript, react-native, charts, react-native-svg-charts

I'm using `react-native-svg-chart' to create pie chart but I'm facing a problem that it's rendering duplicate text at the centre of pie chart(image below).

[image]

here is the code I'm using for it

```
   <PieChart
            style={{height: 262}}
            valueAccessor={({item}) => item.amount}
            data={data}
            outerRadius={'95%'}>
            <Text
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: deviceWidth / 2.3 - labelWidth / 3,
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}>
              hello
            </Text>
            <Labels />
          </PieChart>
```

Comment: Try importing `Text` component from `react-native-svg`, like `import { Text } from 'react-native-svg'`

Comment: I answered as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `Text` component from `react-native-svg`, like

```
import { Text } from 'react-native-svg'
```